# Replacement for WCF ServiceBus Relay in .Net 7

Tags: c#, .net, azure, service-bus

We've leveraged WCF Azure Service Bus Relay fairly heavily in the past and have a number of C# services that rely on it.

All of these services relay REST requests to small on-site servers that sit behind corporate firewalls and are hosted on networks with dynamic public IPs.

We are rapidly approaching the point where we need to move these services in to a newer .NET framework, such as 6 or 7, which has no WCF support.

I am having trouble finding a similar replacement for the WCF Http relay. I've looked at reverse proxy, hybrid connections (which are overkill and too expensive) and writing some kind of custom middleware that both the clients and servers connect to as "clients".

Looking for any advice or suggestions for the easiest way to replace WCF relay without reinventing the wheel.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF, maybe you find something.